# For a given $B$ magnetic flux density in a homogeneous magnetic field what is the separation distance between the flux lines?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, quantum-electrodynamics, vector-fields

For a given $B$ magnetic flux density thus number of lines of force passing through per unit of surface area of a homogeneous magnetic field of parallel flux lines inside a vacuum environment, is there a way to calculate the clearing distance between the flux lines in the field? Are there regular spaces inside the field which are void of magnetic flux?

Is the position of the flux lines subject of the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle?

Comment: The flux line are not physical entities, they just visualize the direction of the force at a point in space. With the same reasoning, there is no such distance between them. Flux lines will exist everywhere, but for a stronger field, the force on the line would be higher. And also, no spaces that are void of magnetic field (unless there are multiple field that cancel each other at certain points)

Comment: That is why the commonly found application of flux conservation stating that the density of field lines increases in the region of space where they converge is plainly stupid. It is equivalent to say they are more points in a one square meter than in a one square centimeter.

Comment: @Shaktyai Good point. I agree. To resolve this paradox  the actual physical explanation is that the magnetic field indeed consists of a finite number of discrete coherent streams of virtual photons thus lines which are separated at least by Plank length scale distances. In quantum electrodynamics there is no continuous field distortion and vacuum void space is always there therefore the threads-fiber  nature of magnetic fields must be true at the microscopic quantum scale.

Answer (score -4):

Quantum electrodynamics and their consequent macroscopic classical electromagnetic phenomena is discrete in nature phenomena and vacuum void space is part of the equation. Thus  coherent distortions  in quantum field cannot be continuous. It may look at such at the macroscopic classical scale but it is not. Even water flow in a river consists at the microscopic level of coherent flow streams of of Hydrogen and Oxygen atoms separated by vacuum space between them inside the water molecule and molecules in a stream are also separated by vacuum gaps (i.e. bear in mind that inside any materiel at atomic and subatomic size scales there is no medium between two atoms but only vacuum space).

Electromagnetic flux is coherent streams of virtual photons linked to electrons and void space is always there between them at least at the *Plank length* scale. So the physical description of a magnetic field and its magnetic flux consisting of what may seem at the macroscopic level of "countless" but still finite number of coherent stream lines of these virtual photons, carriers of the the EM force is valid and actually true.

Therefore, examining the isolated H field of a permanent magnet placed in a vacuum environment,  assuming there are no iron filings present or any other magnetic matter except the permanent magnet, the vacuum gaps between the different discrete streams of flux (i.e. flow of energy) are physically there but there are so small that at the macroscopic classical scale we observe the magnetic flux as a continuous field.

The quantum world consists manly of void vacuum gaps and is elementary discrete and this also applies for the magnetic flux of a magnetic field. The only physical entity that today is not being resolved of being discrete phenomenon is vacuum space itself and considered as contentious by General relativity. Quantization of space prove is one of the main goals of modern quantum gravity theory.

An effective method but not the actual  for representing the magnetic field strength using magnetic flux lines is instead of Tesla units to use Maxwell units thus number of lines per cm^2. For this units a 100μΤ field strength is represented with one line penetrating vertically a one cm^2 surface. This representation is symbolic however and not the actual physical number of lines that macroscopically and practically would appear to us as  "countless" nevertheless is a finite  number.

To get a feeling for example:

This [calculator](https://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/en-US/magnetic-flux-density/) translates Tesla units to Maxwell (lines/cm^2). According, it says that 100μΤ correspond to one line per square cm thus  0.5 cm clearance from every side.

A quick calculation shows a $1T$ field has 10,000 lines/cm^2 which corresponds to a separation distance between the lines of 500 nm *(i.e. there is a line present at regular 500nm intervals in space)* for a homogeneous magnetic field assuming also the flux lines are infinite thin.

Again, this is just a representation of a given field strength using number of lines and the number of lines per field strength used by this unit cannot be taken literally. The discrete magnetic flux lines, streams of virtual photons consisting the field are physically there but in a finite number much much larger as represented by this unit.